# Area of a parametric plot with interpolating functions

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, parametric-functions, integral-equations

I am looking for the area of a parametric plot defined by two solutions (defined as: VVLt & PVLt) of Numerically solved differential equations. The problem is when i'm trying to integrate the two, the integration just gives the interpolating functions.

`ParametricPlot[{VVLt, PVLt}, {t, 7, 10}]
With[{x = VVLt, y = PVLt}, Integrate[y D[x, t], {t, 7, 10}]]`

Which gives me
 [image]
Because the module for solving the differential equations is quite long I've not included these lines. Is there another way to determine the Area of the parametric plot? Thank you!

Comment: Use `NIntegrate` instead of `Integrate` and integrate over one period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a different example that produces a closed curve:

```
sol = NDSolve[{y'[t] == y[t] (x[t] - 1), x'[t] == x[t] (2 - y[t]), 
       x[0] == 1, y[0] == 2.7}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}];
```

[image]

```
pp = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. First[sol]], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

You can extract the closed curve from `pp` and get the `Area` of the enclosed polygon:

```
Area @ Cases[pp , Line[x_] :> Polygon[x[[First@FindCurvePath[x]]]], All][[1]]
```

> 0.892207

Comment: This seems to work perfectly! I do have one more question I would like to ask you. Can you explain the line of code to calculate the Area? I know it's uncommon to ask and I would understand it if you don't want to do it. Anyway thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: @David, you can see inside `pp` using its first part `pp[[1]]` . `Cases[pp, Line[coords_], All]` extracts the objects of the form `Line[...]` from `pp`, and `Cases[pp, Line[coords_]:> foo[coords], All]` modifies those line objects to the form `foo[coords]`. Since the line coordinates (`coords`)  are not necessarily ordered to form a closed polygon we order them using the function `FindCurvePath[coords]`. The result is a polygon and we can apply `Area` or `RegionMeasure` to it to get its area.